# Learning CSS (JavaFx style)

Tags: css, javafx

Recently i switched my GuI and programming to fit Javafx and use the new JavaFx scene builder! These new tools (atleast new for me) has opened alot of doors when it comes to creating user interfaces and i want to learn more and get better at it. Therefore i wish to learn CSS for JavaFx.

So far i have been unable to find any online tutorials for beginners and because of this I want to ask you guys; do you know any sites, books or video tutorials where i can learn to write CSS for JavaFx projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might easily find many good resources simply by Googling.

Here are recommended ones

**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/css)**

**[www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/learning)**

*Note:Stay away from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com).*

[Reason to avoid w3schools](http://w3fools.com/)

**The best way to learn CSS would be to learn it by doing.
Create some web pages and style them no your own.**

Answer (score 6):

For learnIng JavaFX CSS, work through the following tutorials:

- [The JavaFX Getting Started tutorial on CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/css.htm).
- [The JavaFX CSS tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm).

When using SceneBuilder, review:

- [Using a Style Sheet in SceneBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/get_started/preview-stylesheet.htm#BABIDJEI).
- [SceneBuilder Style Sheet Support](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/stylesheet-support.htm#BEHGAGEH).

When developing your own apps, the two most useful resources are:

- The [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).
- The (essential) [JavaFX 2.2 Caspian Style Sheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css) which contains the default styling for all JavaFX controls.

---

If you search the web you will find many resources on CSS and HTML.  Be careful using these resources.  JavaFX CSS is not the same as the CSS you use to style a web page.  While the file format is the same, JavaFX CSS has it's own set of attributes and allowed values, includes few layout processing specifiers, uses it's own syntax for effect processing, background and border specifications, etc.